# Improve Lua syntax highlighting

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) syntax highlighting does not understand that the `'` character is inside a line comment and seems to treat it like the beginning of a string, while it should actually be ignored and highlighted as a comment.

Here's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195033/store-inherited-table-member-into-child-class-if-index-is-invoked-by-object-of) which demonstrates this.

[image: Problem]

**Note:** I assume, that the syntax highlighting picks the language from the question's tags. However, the only sources validating this are from 2010, please forgive me if this system has changed in the meantime.

**Second note:** I added the tag 'iOS', because I experienced this in the iOS-App. Would someone mind checking whether this problem exists on the website, too?

Comment: Seems to work fine on the website. Fails in android app too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We haven't done the legwork necessary to support non "built-in" language support in mobile.  I'll have this updated pretty soon (you know...6-8 weeks).  Also, it's worth pointing out that our [markdown allows you to specify a language hint](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).  In this particular case, prettify is trying to highlight with the default, which doesn't recognize Lua comments.

**Update**: this will be fixed in the next version (**0.1.61+**).  Other languages will benefit too, as we now support (more or less) everything supported by the site.